# convert image to text. problem the image is not text. its well a picture

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

i have a picture, a supposed symbol of a company

i would like to convert that image to text and then display it,

such that

- it appears as an image to the user, (when the user zooms in he realizes that the image is made up of combination of letters)
- it being letters, i can manupilate it usig css

is thr a tool out there?  free  is preferred

Comment: -1, this is not a programming question as asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

http://afterlight.110mb.com/2007/06/11/image-to-text-converters-revisiting-the-old-school-through-ascii-art/